# Ejecutar una consulta al destruir la aplicación

Tags: android-studio

Buen día, estoy tratando de ejecutar un **script PHP** al momento de destruir la aplicación hay manera de hacer algo así? justo antes de que la aplicación de destruya se ejecute la consulta que necesito, lógicamente lo primero que pensé en usar fue `onDestroy();` pero no parece funcionar el código que yo tenga en `onDestroy();`

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //ejecutar mi script php

    }
```

Investigando un poco me doy cuenta que para algo así podría usar `onTaskRemoved` pero parece que desde la **versión 8 (Oreo)** dejo de funcionar...

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    
    //Ejecutar mi script php

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

Entonces no he podido encontrar alternativas para algo así o alguna implementación que hacer para que `onDestroy();` o `onTaskRemoved` me funcionen

Espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Es porque tu script debe ir antes de esto `super.onDestroy();`

Answer (score 0):

Pues, te sugiero que reubiques tu código, de esta manera debería funcionar:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy() muestra el toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: Hola Franqo gracias por la sugerencia, fíjate que ya lo he intentado de esa manera pero sigue sin funcionar!!!